# Как запустить программу в IDEA?

Tags: javascript, spring, intellij-idea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]При запуске появляется это (фото 1). Выбрала пункт Edit Configurations в появившемся меню. Далее Application. Но метод MainController отсутствует. Как это исправить?[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]][1[image: ]]

Comment: Запустить можно только класс, в котором есть статический метод `main`. В вашем случае, т.е. для spring boot на этом классе еще должна быть аннотация `@SpringBootApplication`. Вот его нужно запускать, а не контроллер.

Comment: Аннотацию добавила (на 1 фото). Но запустить всё равно не получается

Comment: Запустить получилось, извините, я в первый раз работаю в этой программе. А если есть какие-то проблемы, но программа запускает, это нормально?